# Install PECL Oauth MAMP OSX 10.8

Tags: php, oauth, mamp

I am trying to install the PECL Oauth extension on OSX 10.8 with MAMP version 2.1.3. This version of MAMP has PHP 5.4.10 and 5.2.17 with it, I have already added the stuff to the include folder of 5.2.17 and run the ./configure. Although when I go to run

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin; ./pecl install oauth
```

I get

```
downloading oauth-1.2.3.tgz ...
Could not download from "http://pecl.php.net/get/oauth-1.2.3.tgz", cannot download "pecl/oauth" (could not open /tmp/pear/install/oauth-1.2.3.tgz for writing)
Error: cannot download "pecl/oauth"
Download failed
install failed
```

Now I am not 100% sure that MAMP is using the 5.2.17 version of PHP, I have changed it in the apache httpd.conf file and when I look at the phpinfo page in MAMP it shows up as using version 5.2.17 so I do not think this is the issue.

Comment: `sudo su -` `cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin` `./pecl install oauth`?

Comment: @mkjasinski Does not appear to be a valid command `su: unknown login: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin`

Comment: `sudo su -` don't work? hmmm... `sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/bin/pecl install oauth`?

Comment: I run that and it seems to download but the end the error is `make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
ERROR: 'make' failed`

Comment: Install [Macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and than: `sudo port install pcre`.

Comment: @mkjasinski I done that, it gave me warnings throughout saying that Xcode is not installed (It is) but no error at the end. I still seem to get the same error as before :/ (the make: ... one).

Comment: write contents of the error with command

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26781/discussion-between-thetechbox-and-mkjasinski)

Comment: I have moved this to a chat so as not to create a very long comment chain, hope that is OK.